# SSIS package execution completed but no errors and Excel destination is empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have an SSIS package that reads data from an Excel source and separates out into invalid data with a reason field or valid data if it passes all my validation checks (i.e. duplication checking, valid responses, etc.).  The invalid and valid files are Excel destination files.

The package runs as expected on my old laptop connected to the network.  I've had to change to a new laptop and worked with IT to install all the same SQL Server software.  On the new machine, connected to the same network with the same login credentials in my data sources, the package does not run as expected.

I click debug and it looks like it's processing as normal and I receive the message, "Package execution completed.  Click here to switch to design mode, or select Stop Debugging from the debug menu."  I stop debugging and it looks like all rows were sent to the invalid Excel file as expected.  But when I open the file, it's empty.  The valid Excel file is also empty.

I'm wondering if there is a compatibility issue with the version of Microsoft Excel on this machine?  This setup has MS Excel 2013 with some patch that allows accessing 2010 version files.  The old setup had MS Excel 2010.  I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sisto

Comment: Any code sample you can provide will increase the likelihood of a helpful response.

Comment: Were any rows sent to the valid file? Why don't you add a watch to the data flow and look at the rows. If there was an issue with the Excel driver it would not work at all. If you open the invalid Excel file BEFORE you run the package, does the package crash because the file is open? Be certain that rows are going to the file, and be certain that you have set the path up correctly.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. I make sure my source data and template Excel files (valid and invalid) are closed prior to running the package.  I also set up a data viewer after the task immediately before the Excel destination and verified that the rows were flowing through the tasks okay, just not ending up in the Excel destination file.  I found that my packages that have SQL destinations work as expected with the rows flowing into the SQL tables, but for some reason the packages with Excel destinations are not receiving rows.  I am at a loss on how to resolve.  Have any suggestions?

Comment: <component id="7929" name="Invalid Data 1" componentClassID="{C9269E28-EBDE-4DED-91EB-0BF42842F9F4}" description="Excel Destination" localeId="-1" usesDispositions="true" validateExternalMetadata="True" version="0" pipelineVersion="0" contactInfo="Excel Destination;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SqlServer v10; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0">
<properties>
<property id="7930" name="CommandTimeout" dataType="System.Int32" state="default" isArray="false" description="The number of seconds before a command times out.  A value of 0 indicates

Comment: It is possible that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523953/permissions-issue-ssis-excel-destination-buffers-large-record-sets-through-c-u) is related to the problem you were seeing.  In that case, the Excel Destination needed access to C:\Users\Default to buffer the output;  otherwise you got an empty Excel file back.