# ACE Oledb 12.0 issue in SSIS package while exporting data to excel

Tags: ssis, excel-2007, oledbconnection, sql-job

I have developed a simple SSIS Package which exports some 10000 rows to an Excel .xlsx file. This package is running fine in my Local BIDS but when scheduled on server using Proxy account It is running successfully but Excel is not loading.

After investigation we found that this issue is happening only when the data size exceeds over 5000 rows. When there is less number of rows, the Job is loading the excel successfully.

I am using ACE OLEDB 12.0 provider and the same is installed on the server. Any idea why the excel is not loading when data size increases.

When the same package is run with .xls excel(Jet provider) then it is loading fine regardless of data size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty Excel File permissions issue: SSIS Excel Destination buffers large record sets through C:\Users\Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523953/empty-excel-file-permissions-issue-ssis-excel-destination-buffers-large-record)

Answer (score 0):

SSIS package works fine in BIDS for loading excel file with more than 5000 rows but failed when same package runs in SQL server Agent Job under proxy account.

Main cause of this is that for large file SSIS process use **C:\Users\Default** location to buffer data. So Proxy account needs write access on this folder location. Package works fine in JOB too after this… Cheers.