# ssis excel import fails if too many rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package that imports an Excel 2013 (xlsx) file into a SQL Server (2016) table. The issue I'm having is that if the file exceeds a certain size, the package fails. The error is:

> Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database. 
>   [DTS.Pipeline] Error: "component "failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

It looks as though it can't see the file / worksheet at all. A couple of interesting notes:

- The package works fine in the SQL Server Data Tools 2015 designer, regardless of file size. It only fails when running it through SSMS in the Integration Services Catalog, or via SQL Agent Job.
- The number of rows at which it fails is not a constant. It appears to depend more on the total amount of data being imported. For example, if the characters per row is smaller, it fails at around 25k rows. If there are more characters per row, it fails around 16k rows. In either case, the total file size when it reaches the failure point is still less than 1MB.
- I have tested with the same known-good record repeated X thousand times, so I know it's not a bad record that's causing the issue.
- Initially the file was located on a network share, but I have moved it to be directly on the server's drive to rule out any network instability. No change.
- I have other packages running on the same SQL server that import 100k records or more, and a far bigger total file size (several MB).

Any thoughts on what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the Excel file size, it is related to the file system permissions. Just check the following:

- That the SQL server account has read permission to the file location
- Check that you have set the `Delay Validation` property of the `Data Flow Task` to true, in case that you are reading the Excel file path from a variable, or passing it as parameter.

Comment: The SQL server account has access. It is able to import the file if it has, say, 14,999 rows, but fails it there are 15,000 (just an example, but I have literally been able to make it fail with the addition of 1 extra row of "good" data).

Delay Validation is set to True (it was set to true already).

I have tried increasing and decreasing the DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize, but no difference. It really seems like it can't even see that the file exists once it reaches a certain row count. 

I also tried changing to a named data range instead of a sheet name. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the amount of data being loaded may require it to be processed in smaller chunks rather than read in all at once.  This reduces the overall memory requirements of the program, though this does require extra logic to handle the transition from one chunk of data to the next.  Normally this should run to completion just fine.  Also, see the link below for some ideas of how this kid of ETL should be done.

https://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-import-ms-excel-data-database/

Answer (score 0):

I found the url at the bottom of this that explained that the account running the SQL job must have permissions on the C\Users\Default folder on the server running the job.  This is because it uses this directory for large buffers.  Or you can add the account running the job to the local administrators account.
[Empty Excel File permissions issue: SSIS Excel Destination buffers large record sets through C:\Users\Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523953/empty-excel-file-permissions-issue-ssis-excel-destination-buffers-large-record)